# What is the most efficient way to send query results between Server and Client

Tags: c#, sql, client-server

I have this Server/Client app written in C#. There is an SQL Server on server side, when client needs a table it sends a request to server application and server application connects to SQL Server and retrieves the table and sends it to client via a NetworkStream.

This is the server side code which sends the DataSet XML Stream

```
using (var networkStream = new NetworkStream(m_workerSocket[0]))
{
     dataSet.WriteXml(networkStream);
}
```

And I'm reading this xml file as bytes and convert it to string and convert it to a DataSet again.
This is client side code:

```
TextReader reader = new StringReader(richTextRxMessage.Text);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(reader);
DataTable dtProd = new DataTable();
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

My question is is this an efficient way to send table between client/server? Would it be a problem with big tables such as 10k entries? What can I do to optimize that?

And there will be a lot of communication between server and client except these tables such as instant messages or different type of files. So how can I handle and classify a lot of data wheter its a file or its a DataSet etc. For example should I put custom string tags (such as `<DATASET>, <DOCFILE>` etc.) before sending data to identify data type that I'm sending?
Thank you.

PS:I'm using Asynchronous Server and Client to sends and recieve data.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Could you put your answer as a regular post so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use WCF for such tasks.
[You can read about it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by efficient. There are several trade offs to make. Are you trying to save bandwidth? Then a plain text format like JSON and XML isn't the way to go. It'd be a better idea to use a protocol that's less verbose and supports compression without having to use Base64 encoding. Of course this means you'll be using more CPU cycles. Also there's caching to be considered. Can you verify if the client's data has been invalidated since it was last requested? If so then a caching mechanism that can store entire sets or even partial sets would save even more bandwidth. Of course this means you'll be using more memory and possibly more hard drive space if you resort to caching directly to the drive.

I think your question has a bit more depth than you realize.